# React js: ErrorTypeError - Can't read property of undefined array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Before passing real time data of a fleet of vessels into a table after an API request, I wanted to try to inject sample data, in fact I hardcoded them. The goal would be: if I can read sample data, than almost surely the API will show the data into the table of all the vessels I am looking for.

However the debugger says that `ErrorTypeError - Can't read property of indefined variable` properly and the `Console` says:

> Response { type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok:
>   false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, body: null, bodyUsed: false }

`ErrorTypeError: this is undefined` if that is useful I am also including a screen-shot of my desktop:

[image: console]

Below the code I am using:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const resultArea = document.getElementById('result');
let out = '';

const fetchConfig = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors'
};

const MapContainer = styled.div`
    // some components
`;

class BoatMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonEnabled: true
        };
        this.updateRequest = this.updateRequest.bind(this);
    }

    updateRequest() {
        const url =
            'http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=My_KEY&format=1&output=json&compress=3&latmin=12.11&latmax=48.95&lonmin=-124.97&lonmax=-58.95';
        console.log(url);
        fetch(url, fetchConfig)
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                return this.dummyData; // <-- Can't read this 
            })
            .then(function(jsonObject) {
                const boatData = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
                 for (boat in jsonObject) {
                    const boatInfo = [
                        // parsing data from the API after confirming with hardcoded dummyData
                     ];
                    boatOut(boatInfo);
                    console.log(boatInfo);
                 }
                resultArea.innerHTML = out;
            })
            .catch(function(e) {
                console.log('Error' + e);
            });
        this.setState({
            buttonEnabled: false
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ buttonEnabled: true });
        });
    }

    dummyData = [
        {
            ERROR: false,
            USERNAME: 'My_KEY',
            FORMAT: 'HUMAN',
            LATITUDE_MIN: 20.5,
            LATITUDE_MAX: 30.8,
            LONGITUDE_MIN: -15,
            LONGITUDE_MAX: 18.6,
            RECORDS: 14
        },
        [
            {
                MMSI: 566619000,
                TIME: '2020-01-25 19:51:38 GMT',
                LONGITUDE: -14.84344,
                LATITUDE: 28.282,
                COG: 15.7,
                SOG: 11.3,
                HEADING: 16,
                ROT: 0,
                NAVSTAT: 0,
                IMO: 9529504,
                NAME: 'NORD SUMMIT',
                CALLSIGN: 'S6RW5',
                TYPE: 70,
                A: 174,
                B: 26,
                C: 20,
                D: 12,
                DRAUGHT: 12.1,
                DEST: 'NO SAU',
                ETA: '02-02 12:00'
            },
            {
                MMSI: 236446000,
                TIME: '2020-01-25 19:51:28 GMT',
                LONGITUDE: -14.83202,
                LATITUDE: 28.64639,
                COG: 38,
                SOG: 12.1,
                HEADING: 38,
                ROT: 3,
                NAVSTAT: 0,
                IMO: 9291561,
                NAME: 'KEY BAY',
                CALLSIGN: 'ZDIJ4',
                TYPE: 83,
                A: 82,
                B: 18,
                C: 1,
                D: 19,
                DRAUGHT: 6.1,
                DEST: 'CASABLANCA',
                ETA: '01-27 15:00'
            }
        ]
    ];

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="google-map">
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'My_KEY' }}
                    center={{
                        lat: 42.4,
                        lng: -71.1
                    }}
                    zoom={11}
                    <button className="btn-next-request" onClick={() => this.updateRequest()}>
                        Time to Next API Request
                    </button>
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) I tried to solve the problem acting directly on the dummyDaya component trying to parse it manually. However the API already gives as answer the template file I included in the `updateRequest()` function. Nothing is shown.

2) I am not sure why I am not able to read the data of the two vessels as I copy/past the answer of the API for the two data. Technically it should be injected with no problem.

3) I am now trying to investigate the possibility that according to the [official documentation](https://www.aishub.net/api) the `dummyData` should not carry (and don't know if I should erase) the initial value of the request when passing the data. What I am referring to is the following part of the `dummyData` array:

```
dummyData = [
            {
                ERROR: false,
                USERNAME: 'My_KEY',
                FORMAT: 'HUMAN',
                LATITUDE_MIN: 20.5,
                LATITUDE_MAX: 30.8,
                LONGITUDE_MIN: -15,
                LONGITUDE_MAX: 18.6,
                RECORDS: 14
            },
[ …...
```

Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `arrow` function to access `this` as component ref/instance. `function` has it's own this which will be misleading

```js
fetch(url, fetchConfig)
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        return this.dummyData; // <-- Can't read this 
    })
```

Same applies to all such function in your code here

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, if you wish to return the response from via `fetch`, you will need to call `Body.json()` to return the `Response` stream.

```
fetch(url, fetchConfig)
  .then((data) => {
     return data.json();
  }).then((data) => {
     console.log(data);
     // do the rest here
  });
```

Next, if you wish the reference `this`, you will need to use arrow functions,

```
fetch(url, fetchConfig)
  .then((data) => {
    return this.dummyData;
  }).then((data) => {
     console.log(data);
     // do the rest here
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create state for dummyData.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     buttonEnabled: true,
     dummyData : [],   // Create state for dummyData
   };
this.updateRequest = this.updateRequest.bind(this);
}
```

Then fetch data(I used `async await`) from your url and set it to dummyData.

```
const request = async () => {
         const url = 'http://data.aishub.net/ws.php? username=My_KEY&format=1&output=json&compress=3&latmin=12.11&latmax=48.95&lonmin=-124.97&l onmax=-58.95';

         const response = await fetch(url, fetchConfig);
         const json = await response.json();
         this.setState(dummyData : json);
    }        

    request();
```